# Amazon logo in oneboxed Amazon links is pixelated

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox, logo

When I post a link to an Amazon product page in chat, the Amazon logo in the onebox is very fuzzy:

> [image: Very fuzzy Amazon logo in chat]

Can someone increase the resolution of the Amazon logo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This icon is supplied by amazon.com at `https://www.amazon.com/favicon.ico`: [image]

The [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is to be displayed with the URL in the address bar, next to shortcuts, etc. It is nominally supplied as a 16x16 image, which explains the pixelation when shown at 48x48:

[image]

**After some investigation:**

The ICO format allows for supplying several resolutions in the resource. Downloading the resource at the URL I give above, it appears that amazon.com supplies a 32x32 pixel image and a 48x48 pixel image. Here is a PNG of the 48x48 image:

[image: 48x48 pixel amazon.com icon]

The fuzzy 48x48 pixel image is simply accessed through an HTML IMG tag. As displayed by my browser, it seems to be scaled to 16x16 then to 48x48.  This is probably how the resource is being accessed in chat. If it is to display the best resolution, the site will need to access the favicon data and pull out the appropriate image instead of simply using an IMG tag.

---

**Update**

The favicon data supplied by amazon.com is now given at 48x48. This bug no longer shows up (and the three images above look identical).

Comment: Your profile picture is horrible :<

Comment: @hims056: thanks, I designed it myself. I'm sorry the mean square does not appeal to you.

Comment: Your profile picture is awesome.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar pfttt liar.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I see the same image 3 times: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLdt1.png

Comment: @Qwertiy: The favicon data seems now to be supplied by amazon.com at 48x48. This bug no longer shows up.

Comment: Yeah, this is a rather awkward edit by the script. I've rolled it back.

Comment: @Glorfindel: I have updated the links and the answer since the bug no longer shows up because amazon.com returns a higher resolution favicon.

Answer (score 3):

The bug appears [to be fixed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4075653#4075653) by now:

> [image]